# How to use Soundcloud api to get stream into html5 audio player?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundcloud

I've just started learning javascript and as my first attempt I'd like to create custom audio player which uses soundcloud's api as a source for music.

So far this is what I got set up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
SC.initialize({
  client_id: '10e27db0dacd00954d7160b4c092a6e2' //Demo ID
});

SC.stream("/tracks/75868018", function(sound){
    $("audio-test").attr("src", sound.uri);
});
};
</script>



</head>
<body>

<audio id="audio-test" controls></audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need a little more to go on than this - can you put the javascript control code in a pastebin so we can take a glance?

Comment: @CodeMoose added it, also added link to blog post which I'm using for this html5 player.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, got it figured out. The problem was the .stream() - it's meant to deliver a prepackaged player, deployed by the .play() function.

If you use `SC.get()` instead, you'll actually access the properties of the track, and be able to embed it in an audio tag. See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/LpzpK/6/

There's still a problem - the tracks are marked as 401 forbidden, so the player is only ever "Loading". You'll have to find a way to make the tracks you want to play public.

Comment: Thank you for great help, I think I've seen a glimpse of how to deal with 401 forbidden somewhere in documentation, I'll try to figure it out ;)

Comment: got it working! just need to append /stream?client_id=YOUR_ID  to sound.uri ;)) thnx again for help!

Comment: @Ilja did you guys get a solution for this

Comment: @Lakshay, not really we went with spotify api in the end and manually embedding souncloud url for tracks that were not available on it. That was a while ago though, I'm sure their api has changed a lot since, maybe this is now possible.

Answer (score 2):

At a cursory glance, it looks like all soundcloud API objects come with a URI property that links directly to the resource. In your case, it would be `sound.uri`.

At the top of your player code, you have an `<audio>` tag - my guess is you'll want to set it's `src` to the URI value for the track you're playing. You can do this by attaching an ID to it and calling

```
SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
    $("[audio_id]").attr("src", sound.uri);
});
```

replacing `[audio_id]` with whatever ID you choose for the tag. You'll probably still have to do something to reinitialize/restart the player each time it changes, but that will hopefully get you started. Let me know how it works!

Comment: Tried it doesn't seem to work. I simplified my player dramatically to better understand everything, but I still can't get it to work, here is my new code http://pastebin.com/A76pgjMf

Comment: I'll drop this into a fiddle and toy around with it - back to you in a bit

Comment: I'm not getting the callback function to run. Do you have to do anything to instantiate the object (var SC = new soundcloud();) or something?

Comment: Let me check documentation

Comment: Can you see that "sound" function, not sure but, should it be somehow called when user clicks the play button, so it puts that src in?

Comment: Yes - when the user clicks play, it should call a function that has that SC.stream in it. I can't really test it without asking for your app_id though

Comment: I created demo app which I'll than delete, but for now you can test it with this id: 10e27db0dacd00954d7160b4c092a6e2

Comment: It doesn't alert anything, but in console it says that it can't find variable sound ;/

Comment: Thanks - just found it myself =o)

Comment: I found this method SC.stream(trackPath, [options], [callback]) , I think that trackPath could be what we need instead of sound.uri ? You can read more on that page we found.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25556/discussion-between-ilya-knaup-and-codemoose)