# Get audio src url status JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio, soundcloud

I'm streaming audio to my player from Soundcloud API.

```
<audio></aidio>
<source src="soundcloud-track-url"></source>
```

I have onerror eventListener for `<audio>` and for `<source>` tags.

If stream is not loading (from source tag) it triggers `onerror`, but I don't know how to verify that this is because that the [per day limit](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits) already reached.

So my logic: `if` I get an error on src load I want to split further, `if` this is because of "limits" - do this, `if` it is not because of "limits" - do that.

If per day limits are reached Soundcloud API return an HTTP 429 response code "Too Many Requests".

How do I can utilize "HTTP 429" information to get the expected result?

Comment: Could you kindly share some code? How are you using that API? Where are your `if` statements?

Comment: Inside onerror eventListener @mrReiha

Comment: You joking, right? I meant show me them by *where are those?*.

Comment: I'm only streaming from that API, not using them per se @mrReiha

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an attribute like `event` to your error handler and then get its `target` property which points to the HTML element that raised the error.

Once you have the element itself, it is easy to fetch its src attribute using `.getAttribute('src')`.

Once you have the src attribute, you can `fetch` to it and check the error status for that request.

```
document.getElementById("mySource").onerror = event => {
    var sourceElement = event.target;
    var audioURL = sourceElement.getAttribute("src");

    fetch(audioURL).then(function(response) {
        alert(response.status);
    });
};
```

Here's sandbox on how this would work:

https://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/GzWdmg?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any sort of clue in your question, I'm just guessing you're using AJAX to communicate with SoundCloud.

Given that, you need to check for `status` property on your `xhr`( XMLHttpRequest ) object.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function( e ) {

    // `xhr.status` is what you're looking for.
    // you can check if it matches your expected 429 or not 
    if ( xhr.status == 429 && xhr.readyState == 4 ) {

        // do whatever you want

    }

}
```

*Update:* due to using the wrong method at first place, I would suggest you read [this same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208512/how-to-use-soundcloud-api-to-get-stream-into-html5-audio-player) people had and look how they've solved it.

Comment: Actually, no, one and only part of communication with Soundcloud is the url inside source tag (scr), no JS or other not involved here on my side @mrReiha

Comment: @AndrewK There is no way to get the HTTP status from a request made by an `audio` tag in JavaScript. The only way to do this is using an AJAX ( or fetch ) call from JS to be able to get the status code of request.

Comment: Can you possibly post it as an answer? So in case of error `onerror eventlistener function` get src url from the tag and check it via JS to HTTP 429 if it matches  @mrReiha

Comment: @AndrewK I'm telling u, you have to set up an Ajax call and use that to get audio from sound cloud. I've updated my answer with link to a similar problem.